# How to increase limit of local variables

Tags: c#, .net

I have a very huge method, where I'm try to create more local variables than the .NET Framework supports. Approximately size of lines of code is 147000 and count of local variables is approximately 75000. I found this article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/919514 but here told that this problem in .net 2.0, but I'm using .net 4.0 in Windows 8.1. Can I increase manually limit of local variables?

My project is simple console application which generate .docx file.

Comment: 147K lines and 75K variables? A "simple console application" - maybe you're asking the wrong question here. Normally, I'd say "post some code" ... but .... please don't ;-)

Comment: how about refactoring?

Comment: Some kind of "spaghetti code" is this method...

Comment: It's auto generated code from open xml sdk 2.5, and yes after small refactor I have 147k lines and 75k variables

Comment: Ouch.  I hope I never have to debug that method!

Comment: If it's auto generated then he's probably best off not refactoring, and just re-auto generating for any problems.  Isn't this more of a problem with the SDK than the framework, though?

Comment: R u writing New OS in single method ?

Comment: @pm_2 exactly - like I said, he's asking the wrong question

Comment: I think you should post the method - let's see how SO deals with 147K lines of code posted :-)

Comment: Has April Fools day come early?

Comment: You're having a massive coding smell here!!!! Don't even try to increase the limit! Instead make your methods smaller (20 lines are enough)!

Comment: He's already explained this is auto generated code.  There's not much point in telling him to refactor.

Comment: Are the variables that are generated in the form of int p1, int p2, etc?  Could you do a search / replace to reuse?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are just running into a rock-hard limitation in MSIL, the code that's generated by the C# compiler.  A local variable is loaded with the [Opcodes.LdLoc instruction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.ldloc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  There are several variants of this instruction, optimized for common cases.  I linked to the "maximum" one, it takes a 16-bit unsigned index for the local variable index.  Encoded as 4 bytes in the MSIL:

```
 FE 0C < unsigned int16 >
```

The hotfix you found was to work around a jitter bug that interpreted the index as a signed value instead of an unsigned one.  Making the code bomb when the method has more than 32767 local variables.

But, clearly, you can never ever have more than `UInt16.MaxValue+1` indices.  Which is 65,536.  With 75,000 variables, you exceeded that limitation.

There is no workaround for this, you **must** limit the number of local variables and keep it below 65536.

Comment: +1 *"keep it below 65536"* - preferably *well* below.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to break this up into smaller methods/classes. That's a huge file, and eventually someone other than you will have to support it.

The trick isn't to find some way to get the runtime to allow more locals, it's to write decent code in the first place. Oh, and anything this big doesn't fall into the "simple console application" category!

Comment: Yes I'm breaking up into classes ~= 5-6k of variables per each, but still have the same issue

Comment: If this is a "simple console application", I am curious about what the OP considers "a fairly complicated application", let alone a "damn complex application" :D

Comment: @BorHunter - The thing is, you can't possibly need this number of variables! It'd be interesting if you could post a small nugget of code, just so we can see what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

A big method can contain as up to 20 or 25 lines. Some programers will tell you that even 20 lines for a method is too much. You must divide this method to a large amout of diffrent method. The code you discribe is abviously a poor code and a one that very hard to debug, understand or fix.